# restoring the table using aggregated information

Tags: r

Is it possible to create again the same df table using only information from the pvt_edu, pvt_sex, pvt_age tables?
I am sending this piece of code as an example, I tried to use gpt but it creates tables that do not have the same structure as the original df from which they are then created pvt~

```
library('tidyverse')

sex <- c('M','F')
age <- c('18-25','26-34','35-50','51-65','66-99')
education <- c("No education", "Primary", "Secondary")
residence <- c('village','town','city')
size=150

df <- 
  data.frame(sex=sample(sex,size,T)
           ,age=sample(age,size,T)
           ,education=sample(education,size,T)
           ,residence=sample(residence,size,T)
           )

pvt_age <- 
  df %>% 
  group_by(age,residence)  %>% 
  count

pvt_sex <- 
  df %>% 
  group_by(sex,residence)  %>% 
  count

pvt_education <- 
  df %>% 
  group_by(education,residence)  %>% 
  count
```

Comment: If you are asking whether given marginals the data set is unique then the answer is no, generally it is not.

Answer (score 0):

It is in general not possible to reconstitute the data set from aggregate counts or other aggregate statistics.
Base function [`r2dtable`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/r2dtable.html) can construct random 2-way tables with given marginals but those two-way tables are not unique, like the function description implies. As a matter of fact, you can even ask for `n` such two-way tables, all different.

```r
set.seed(2023)
sex <- c('M','F')
age <- c('18-25','26-34','35-50','51-65','66-99')
education <- c("No education", "Primary", "Secondary")
residence <- c('village','town','city')
size=150

df <- 
  data.frame(sex=sample(sex,size,T)
             ,age=sample(age,size,T)
             ,education=sample(education,size,T)
             ,residence=sample(residence,size,T)
  )

# tbl is pvt_sex with different format
tbl <- table(df[c("sex", "residence")])
sex <- rowSums(tbl)
res <- colSums(tbl)

r2dtable(2L, sex, res) |>
  lapply(\(x) {
    dimnames(x) <- list(names(sex), names(res))
    x
  })
#> [[1]]
#>   city town village
#> F   24   29      27
#> M   25   26      19
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   city town village
#> F   32   28      20
#> M   17   27      26
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>